# App Crash setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

In my application i asked user to draw sign and then i show that image in UIImageView using below Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(captureView.bounds.size);

[captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[ivStudentSign setImage:viewImage];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tempDict setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) forKey:userID];
[arrStoreSigns addObject:tempDict];
[userDef setObject:arrStoreSigns forKey:@"storeSigns"];
```

it almost works fine but sometime i get

> setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil

that makes my application crash.What i'm doing wrong?I'm running application on ios 8.4.1

Comment: Looks like `viewImage` is nil... The error is pretty clear.

Comment: but how that possible ? 'UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()' never return nil

Comment: Add a break point and step through the code.

Comment: May be `arrStoreSigns` is not initialized.

Comment: `arrStoreSigns` is `nil`.

Comment: arrStoreSigns is not nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To figure this out, you need to go backward.

The object is nil, this means `arrStoreSigns` is nil. And `arrStoreSigns` is nil because `tempDict` is nil. `tempDict` is nil since `UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)` doesn't give you any value, hence it become `nil`. This may happen since `viewImage` is nil due to `UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` returning a `nil` image.

You put breakpoints and check, which of them above is actually failing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you point to the documentation which says NSMutableDIctionary cannot have nil object

Comment: "Neither a key nor a value can be nil" here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the crash log. `setObjectForKey` method requires an object which is not nil to be set to the `NSDictionary`. Check whether you are getting required values for `UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)` or `arrStoreSigns`

Answer (score 0):

In NSMutableDictionary, one can't set nil value for a key. It can be a NULL object.
To ensure that nil and NULL object must not insert into dictionary, you can use following code snippet to avoid crash.

```
if (anObject != [NSNull null] && anObject != nil) {
     [self setObject:anObject forKey:aKey];
}
```

here anObject can be your image object and self can be your tempDict.

Your code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(captureView.bounds.size);

[captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[ivStudentSign setImage:viewImage];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if (viewImage != [NSNull null] && viewImage != nil) {
    [tempDict setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)   forKey:userID];
    [arrStoreSigns addObject:tempDict];
    [userDef setObject:arrStoreSigns forKey:@"storeSigns"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you point to the documentation which says NSMutableDIctionary cannot have nil object